# Visual Studio 2017 cannot create or open .shproj (shared Project) files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, shared-project

I have recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6.3. After doing so (and fixing a bunch of other issues), I can no longer open or create .shproj files.

My existing projects say **(load failed)** next to each shared project file, and I have the following in my output window whenever I try reloading the project:

> C:\File\Path\Project.Shared.shproj : error  : Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory+ProjectLoadHelper" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.

Similarly if I try to create a new shared project, I get the same message in a popup:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Expected 1 export(s) with contract name Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory+ProjectLoadHelper" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.

Why is Visual Studio not allowing me to load or create .shproj files and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the entire folder at UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio (idea from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/190581/1560-preview-3-breaks-azure-functions-projects.html) and now my .sproj files load.