# Why won't Visual Studio open my project after upgrading from 15.7.X -> 15.9.X

Tags: visual-studio, upgrade

I recently upgraded Visual Studio to try to resolve another problem, but now I'm being hit by a new one. When I try to open a .sln file which opened fine in Visual Studio 2017, I get the following error message:

Microsoft Visual Studio

> The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.SharedProjectFilesPackage.SharedProjectFilesPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_2f0e30dc\ActivityLog.xml'.
>
> Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.
>
> Continue to show this error message?
>   Yes   No

I have tried deleting the `UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio` folder, as that seems to have solved other problems:

[Visual Studio 2017 cannot create or open .shproj (shared Project) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416820/visual-studio-2017-cannot-create-or-open-shproj-shared-project-files)

That didn't help in this case, though.

How can I solve this problem and load my project again?

Update: Completely uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio did not solve the problem either.

Update 2: Creating a brand new Xamarin.Forms project also failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSBuild strikes again!

The solution was to uninstall MSBuild from the GAC:

[Could not load type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.SdkReference' on project open in VS 2017 U1 (15.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738512/could-not-load-type-microsoft-build-framework-sdkreference-on-project-open-in)

Seems like this solution solves everything (this isn't the first time I've had to do this).

Comment: Hi, so glad to hear that your issue is solve, you can mark you reply as answer and that will help others to easier search this information, thanks in advance